# Password Protecting a Form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am trying to password protect one of my forms but receive an error when launching the form.

Here is the error I receive:

The expression on Open you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Procedure declaration does not much description of event or procedure having the same name.

Here is my code:

```
Option Compare Database

    Public Sub Form_Open()
 Cancel = (InputBox("Password?") <> "Cen")

End Sub

Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

On Error GoTo Click_Err
    If Nz(txtReportDate, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "NOTICE! Please enter the Report Month you wish to Import."

       Else

   ' Dim rs As Recordset
    'Dim sql As String

    'Loop through recordset of all Contracts and import files
   ' sql = "SELECT DISTINCT FROM AAABBC_CE"
   ' Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
   ' rs.MoveLast
  '  rs.MoveFirst
   ' If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
       ' Do While rs.EOF = False
           ' ImportFile rs!DISTINCT
           ' rs.MoveNext
       ' Loop
   ' End If

    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox "Finished Importing!"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "query_Files_Loaded_CE", acViewNormal, acReadOnly

click_Exit:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Exit Sub

Click_Err:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    MsgBox "Error Detected: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume click_Exit

       Exit Sub
```

Comment: I figured out how to password protect it, but I assume this doesnt stop the user from actually editing the VB code.

Comment: Rather than hard-coding a password in the VBA code, you could query Active Directory and determine whether the current authenticated user (you're on a network, right?) is in a user group that grants him access to the functionality. That way at least no password appears in plain text anywhere... but your user could always break execution and skip the procedure. Password-protecting the VBA code itself would alleviate that, but it's not impossible to crack either.

Comment: If querying AD is too cumbersome, just test if the user can access a folder that is access-controlled by AD, as a *proxy* for querying AD.

Answer (score 1):

Your Form_Open declaration is incorrect, it doesn't contain parameter. Should be like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
```